# Elasticsearch combining scores in more complex ways

Tags: http, elasticsearch, request

Let's say we make the following search request:

```
GET my-index-000001/_search
{
  query: {
    multi_match: {
      type: "most_fields",
      query: "word1 word2",
      fields: [
        "name",
        "name.prefix",
        "name.suffix"
      ]
    }
  }                  
}
```

This way the returned score for each object in the Elasticsearch index is equal to the sum of scores of searches of each of the following fields: "name", "name.prefix", "name.suffix". How could I, instead of getting the sum of all those fields, get the following score (searchResult(field) means score obtained from field, maximum() returns the maximum score): score = searchResult("name") + maximum(searchResult("name.prefix"), searchResult("name.suffix")) ? Or in other words, how can I get the sum of the score of one field and of the maximum of the scores of other two fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dis_max](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-dis-max-query.html) query to get max score

> If a returned document matches multiple query clauses, the dis_max query assigns the document the highest relevance score from any matching clause, plus a tie breaking increment for any additional matching subqueries.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "dis_max": {
            "queries": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "name.prefix": "word1 word2"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "name.suffix": "word1 word2"
                }
              }
            ],
            "tie_breaker": 0.7
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "name.full_name": "word1 word2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

should clause will give sum of name.full_name and dis_max query

If you will run using _search?explain=true
you will get explanation of how scores are calculated

```
"_explanation" : {
          "value" : 1.3521059,
          "description" : "sum of:",
          "details" : [
            {
              "value" : 0.7767416,
              "description" : "max plus 0.7 times others of:",
              "details" : [
                {
                  "value" : 0.2876821,
                  "description" : "sum of:",
                  "details" :[....]
            },
                {......}        
          ]
            },
        {
              "value" : 0.5753642,
              "description" : "sum of:",
              "details" : [
        .........
              ]
            }
         ]
  }
```